# jquery - theming an input of type "file"

Tags: jquery, file, button, input, themes

Any idea on how to apply a jQuery theme to an input button of type "file"

(ex)

```
<input type="file" value="A submit button">
...
$( "input:file").button();
```

Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to post an image.  However, the inner "Choose File" button does not get themed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try something like this: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 1):

There are various plugins for that. You can for example try [filestyle](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle).